# How to halt Ionic 4 App from "start" until it gets all the needed data

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

On Ionic 3 we could "halt" the app on App Components and get all the data we need before set the rootpage to any page we want it.

But how can I do this on the new version. I'm making a "port" of my app from Ionic 3 to 4 and could not figure it out how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `Resolve Guard`. Its task is to get the data needed for a component to load without first loading the template and then trying to populate it.

Once you get that data, based on the it, you can dynamically load whatever component you want to.

I have created a small example (it is in angular but very much applicable to ionic as well) at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-resolve-service

There are mainly 3 parts to it.

1. We need to create a route resolve service which implements the `Resolve` interface and the `resolve` method to return an `Observable` of data you want to pre load.
2. Do the route configuration in which pass an object to the resolve parameter. The vale of the object refers to your `Resolve` service and the key refers to daa property which would refer to the data returned.

   ```
   resolve: { data: HomeResolverService }
   ```
3. In you component where you need to fetch this data, you can inject the `ActivatedRoute` service to get the data parameter to your component and read it as

   ```
   constructor(private _ar: ActivatedRoute) {
       this.data = this._ar.snapshot.data['data'];
   }
   ```

Comment: That is close to what I need to achieve, yes :D :D Can you show me the demo?